# How to install firefox 20 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, firefox, downgrade

I am using Firefox version 21, but it is too slow and many a time hangs the system.

I want to downgrade my Firefox to version 20.

Please tell me how to install through ppa repository or other method.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a very bad idea to downgrade your browser. The newer version brings with it a lot of security fixes, and installing an older version will open up holes that you probably don't want to open up. My advice: It'd be a far better idea to try and debug *why* certain sites are causing firefox to hang.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @JezW, can you try disabling plugins and then reenabling them one at a time to see if they're causing your problems?

Comment: Downgrading is not a good option. Take a look at the firefox help center to face the problem.

Comment: Firefox 22 is now out. Maybe that solves your problems. Try upgrading. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Like Jez W suggested it is not advisable to downgrade your browser. But if you still want to down grade use the following link to download:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

It was provided by mozilla with every version of firfox.

Comment: Have you ever considered that for web development you need to install a specific version, for example current Selenium WebDriver doesn't support Firefox 22. I know it's not his reason, but I found this question because of that.

Comment: Another +1 for Selenium compatibility. Selenium officially only supports Firefox 10, which is unfortunate but better than no tests at all. Ubuntu's firefox upgrade completely broke all my Selenium tests.

Comment: Me hate Selenium -_- :D